# MediaCodec in MVVM

Tags: android, mvvm, android-mediacodec

I just started using `MVVM`, and having a hard time figuring out what would be the right place to put `MediaCodec` and `MediaCodec.Callbak` in `MVVM` architecture?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Clean architecture]

In MVVM architecture and with clean architecture your MediaCodec belongs to framework layer
So it need to be on this layer
Not in View nor ViewModel.
Si your view call à viewModel which call à useCase and this use case is calling à datasource interface , and the Implementation of the datasource , you will use the MediaCoder api

Comment: If I understood the picture correctly, `View` belongs to the framework layer as well, why wouldn't they connect directly on the same layer?

Comment: Yes it's framework layer as DB also , but we have also the pattern of separation of concerns 
it means Views don't contains complicated logic ( just loops , if else ..) , view is here just to render data received from the viewModel,
so Your view just know the viewModel

Comment: how would I pass a `Surface` to the `MediaCodec.configure()` method in that case?